# Deleted Questions, Duplicate Accounts

Tags: discussion

I flagged a question earlier this evening by user3551983 for undoing edits to math formatting, as well as two other poorly formatted posts. The user then deleted all three of his threads. I saw an identical question (not the one I flagged, but one of user3551983's questions) pop up by user259278, still unformatted. So I formatted it and answered the question. The OP (user259278) then deleted the question. I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate account.

My concerns are two-fold. First, since I took the time to answer the question, I feel my efforts were wasted since the thread is gone and can't be used as a resource. Second, it seems a tad unethical to me to register multiple accounts to ask the same question, but not to adhere to the rules of the site (i.e., math formatting so we can read the question) to get better help. The second is definitely more a moderative issue, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the post in question undeleted. Unfortunately, I don't have any such link to provide.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/closed-questions-being-deleted-and-re-asked-as-new-questions). Flag it for the moderators, and use the text-box to explain that you've already answered the question. The community consensus seems to be in strong agreement that it's unethical or undesirable for such deletions to occur.

Comment: I've flagged one of user3551983's (now deleted) questions, but unfortunately don't have a link to user259278's question to flag. I run private browsing, so I can't look them up in my history. Is there a nice way for me to flag a user or find a deleted question?

Comment: To clarify, both user3551983 deleted all his questions. Then user259278 popped up, posted, got help, and deleted his question.

Comment: @T.Bongers: This situation is a bit tricky, since under some circumstances (which I'm not 100% clear on), flags may be cleared upon deletion of a post.

Comment: I don't think flags are auto-cleared. My original flag on user3551983's thread is still active. Funny enough, a new (low quality) thread from user259278 popped up. I flagged it, so hopefully that will help a moderator look into it.

Comment: The original questions (for 10k users): [one deleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762312/graph-theory-proof-explanation), [two deleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762560/graph-theory-proof) and [rollback war deleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762583/bridges-graph-theory). I don't have links for the re-posts, though.

Comment: Can you look up deleted threads by users? There is one such thread here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762643/graph-theory-proof-isomorphism

The other question (the one I answered and am asking about) was about independent sets, if that helps.

Comment: I can't look up other people's self-deleted threads. That's for the moderators. You can look up your browser history and find links, though.

Comment: I'm using private browsing, so I can't be of any help there. :-(

Comment: I don't see what's up for _discussion_ here. The moderators are looking into the flags, but it does take time to investigate and decide on a course of action. Additionally, there really isn't anything regular members can do. All in all, I don't see any reason why this meta-thread should exist at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, sometimes I favorite a post if I think it will be self deleted. Is a favorite by an under-10K user of any use in a deleted post being found?

Comment: @Will: I think so. I'm not sure if a user can see his own deleted-favorites, but I'm pretty sure that a 10k users can see other people's deleted-favorites.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I know, I have several favorites that have been deleted. Go to my profile on Main and see if you are shown those...that will be part evidence, anyway

Comment: @Will: I can see them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, well, it does work if both people are 10K, you still have favorite http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695762/how-can-i-study-mathematics-and-still-have-a-healthy-and-social-lifestyle-will

Comment: @Will: How about on MathOverflow (where I'm not a 10k user just yet)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, good idea, just a minute

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that worked, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153639/do-not-study-any-theory-of-professor-jeff-because-they-are-all-from-outer-space

Comment: @Will: I don't see any deleted favorites on my profile (yet). So I suppose it's settled then.

Comment: Arthur Fischer- I apologize for the inappropriate meta thread. As I was unable to raise a flag on a deleted thread, my inquiry was more to raise such a flag.

Comment: @ml0105, you do not have any favorites chosen. Evidently, if you do that and the post is deleted, 10K users will be able to see the link in your favorite list and go to the post. Could be handy sometime.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @WillJagy: Perhaps your last comment is an answer to an implicit question in the OP.

Comment: I think the discussion about what moderators can do, and what 10K+ users can try has covered quite a bit.  What hasn't been discussed is, why, after the details you give, you chose to **answer** the repeated question, anyway. Part of community moderation also involves our choices with respect to what we choose to answer.  That's a (mse community) matter that doesn't require 10K+.  Any one who answers what they themselves recognize as a poor question, let alone a duplicated question, ought not expect nor be disappointed when the asker deletes and disappears behind yet another username.